# MySQL max and min explanation

Tags: mysql, max, union, min

My question is for someone to explain how this works. I am getting the MAX and MIN in the ItPrice column. Another student showed me that this works, but couldn't really explain what was going on. I understand that the union is just repeating the same code with the > sign flipped to return min instead of max, so I only need a walkthrough of one half. Heres the question:

> Write a query to list the Triptypes which are associated with the
>   highest and the lowest itinerary prices.

```
select  triptype.tid, triptype.tname, it1.itprice
    from triptype, custitinerary it1
    where triptype.tid = it1.tid 
    and it1.itprice > ALL
        (select itprice from custitinerary it2 
        where it1.ItPrice != it2.Itprice)
Union
select  triptype.tid, triptype.tname, it1.itprice
    from triptype, custitinerary it1
    where triptype.tid = it1.tid 
    and it1.itprice < ALL
        (select itprice from custitinerary it2 
        where it1.ItPrice != it2.Itprice);
```

[image: This is the result from this code]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand the sql provided. But a solution to your problem could be as the following:

I will assume that you have the following tables:

**triptype table:**

```
id,
tripType
```

**itinerary table:**

```
id,
itineraryPrice,
tripType_id,
```

Then your query to get the highest and lowest tripTypes associated with the itinerary price could be calculated as the following:

**First the query to get the highest tripType**

```
SELECT tripType.id, tripType.name, MAX(itinerary.itineraryPrice) as 'price'
FROM tripType, itinerary
WHERE itinerary.tripType_id = tripType.id
```

This will result the following row:

```
------------------------------
| id   | name    | price     |
|------|---------|-----------|
| 42   | Sports  | 16000.00  |
------------------------------
```

**Secondly the query to get the lowest tripType**

```
SELECT tripType.id, tripType.name, MIN(itinerary.itineraryPrice) as 'price'
FROM tripType, itinerary
WHERE itinerary.tripType_id = tripType.id
```

This will result the following row:

```
--------------------------------
| id   | name      | price     |
|------|-----------|-----------|
| 11   |Adventure  | 2000.00   |
--------------------------------
```

**Last Step**

Use UNION to combine both rows (Queries) into a single result:

```
SELECT tripType.id, tripType.name, MAX(itinerary.itineraryPrice) as 'price'
FROM tripType, itinerary
WHERE itinerary.tripType_id = tripType.id
UNION
SELECT tripType.id, tripType.name, MIN(itinerary.itineraryPrice) as 'price'
FROM tripType, itinerary
WHERE itinerary.tripType_id = tripType.id
```

The last step will give you the final result as follows:

```
-------------------------------
| id   | name      | price     |
|------|-----------|-----------|
| 42   | Sports    | 16000.00  |
|------|-----------|-----------|
| 11   | Adventure | 2000.00   |
-------------------------------
```